# jmeter conditional execution after "response code" assertion

Tags: json, testing, automation, jmeter, extract

I'm trying to automate my test.

Basically it's a JSON request to get information about user.

My objective is to drive the response assertion through two different JSON assertion.

One for Positive Test Case, the other one for the Negative Test Case.

I've tried to implement this scenario:

```
ThreadGroup
 + Http Request
  + CSV Data Set Config -> set input and expected result
  + HTTP Header Manager -> get token from previous request
  + Regular Expression Extractor -> get Response Code
+ if Controller OK (${responseCode}=="200")
  + JSON Assertion
+ if Controller NOK (${responseCode}=="400")
  + JSON Assertion
```

[image: getProfile]

this is the Regular Expression Extractor:
[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

this is the If Controller conf:
[image: IfController]

But the "if controller" doesn't works, it means that the JSON Assertion is not called.

Do you know how to fix it, or another way to do it ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Follow [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) example:

> ```
> "${VAR}" == "abcd"
>
> ${__groovy(vars.get("myVar") != "Invalid" )}
> ```

Change it to

```
 "${responseCode}" == "200"
```

Or

```
 ${__groovy(vars.get("responseCode") == "200" )}
```

Comment: both solutions doesn't works. the checkResponseJSON (JSON Assertions) are not executed at all. so it means that the If Controller fails

Comment: The assertion can work only on sampler in their scope and you have none, you can't put assertion of previous sampler inside if controller. see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder

Comment: is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: You can use Or conditions in Response Assertion " OR Apply each assertion in OR combination (if 1 pattern to test matches, Assertion will be ok)". see more in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an Assertion per se, assertions are being applied to [Sampler(s)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers). Given you don't have any Samplers under the If Controllers nothing will be executed there.

In general you cannot switch to this or that assertion using If Controller, the only way you can keep your current Test Plan structure is using a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) and [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to copy your `[${TEST_DESC]` sampler response data to the Dummy Sampler.

Example Test Plan outline:

- `[${TEST_DESC]`

  - responseCode
- If Controller #1 with condition `${__jexl3(${responseCode}=="200",)}`

  - Dummy Sampler with "Response Data" `${__groovy(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),)}`

    - Check response json ok
- If Controller #2 with Condition ``${__jexl3(${responseCode}=="400",)}`

  - Dummy Sampler with "Response Data" `${__groovy(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),)}`

    - Check response json not ok

You can install the Dummy Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the IF Controller and there you can place the string as ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} this will check the response of the previous request and it will work accordingly..!!